# How to define asymptotes of a fuction below?

Tags: calculus, functions, asymptotics

Please, help. I know there is no horizontal and vertical asymptotes, but how to prove it using $k_1$ and $b_1$ formulas? 
$(x-1)^{2/3}(x+1)^3$

Comment: Since the function domain is $\mathbb{R}$ then there is no vertical asymptote and looking limit as x to infinity tells that there are no horizontal asymptotes,btw what are the k1 and b1 formulas

Comment: The formula for k1 is actually the same as you wrote below. And b1 is the limit of f(x)-k1. Our professor just calls it 'k1 and b1 formulas' . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by $k_1$ and $b_1$ formulas you mean the formulas for computing the slope and the $y$-intercept of the asymptote. In this case what happens is that 
$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{(x-1)^{2/3}(x+1)^3}{x}=\infty,
$$
and $k_1$ is not defined.